# How to close the current extension tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to close the Options page of the extension.
I have a Cancel button and I'm using this code:

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function() {});
});
```

When I'm trying to use it, it always gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getCurrent' of undefined
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It works for me with one little fix:

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function() { });
});
```

Just make sure you're really running this code in options page of your extension and not just some HTML page, because chrome.tabs API is available only for extensions.

Comment: do you need permisions??

Comment: just checked you don't  ++`1`

Comment: I get an error running this code in Edge: "Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined".

Comment: @gornvix getCurrent doesn't work in the background page. And getSelected is now deprecated. I had to use tabs.query. Check T.Todua's answer and my comment

Answer (score 13):

Most likely you're running your code from a content script, where chrome.tabs is undefined. If this is the case, you can instead [send a message](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to the background page and have the background page (which has access to chrome.tabs) make the call.

Note that from a background page, you would use `chrome.tabs.getSelected` since `getCurrent` will return undefined.

Comment: `..getSelected` is deprecated. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected

Answer (score 4):

In the options page, you can just do:

```
window.close()
```

If you wanted to use `chrome.tabs.getCurrent`, do you have `tabs` defined in the permissions section within the [manifest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#manifest)?

Comment: I know I could use window.close(), but I want to do it the other way. :) I have defined tabs permission.

Answer (score 3):

Only this worked for me:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function(tabs) {  
    chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[0].id);   
});
```

Comment: This seems to close random tabs and not the current tab. I had to add `currentWindow: true` along with `active: true` in query options for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have time to continue my extension after a very long time. I checked the documentation again. So it was a inline script, that I had probably blocked with Content Security Policy in the manifest, because I hadn't read the documentation precisely.
Now Chrome blocks inline scripts by default, so I'll have to fix it anyway.