# closing the current tab in a chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am writing a chrome extension that when clicked, will close the current tab after a given amount of time.
I am sending a message with the time, from *popup.js* to *background.js*. But the tab won't close.
The alert works when I uncomment it, so it seems to be just the remove line. I assume it's something about `tab.id`.

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function message(request, sender, callback) {
        var ctr = 0;
        ctr = parseInt(request.text, 10);
        setTimeout(function() {
            chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
                //window.alert("Working?");
                chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function(){});
            });
        }, ctr);
    }
);
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104973/how-to-close-the-current-extension-tab

Comment: That is where I initially found the solution

Comment: Are you requesting the `tabs` permission in your manifest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.**
**chrome.extension** has no `onMessage` event. I assume you mean the correct **chrome.runtime.onMessage**

**2.**
You have probably misunderstood(*) the purpose of **[chrome.tabs.getCurrent](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-getCurrent)**:

> Gets the tab that this script call is being made from. May be undefined if called from a non-tab context (for example: a background page or popup view).

Since, you are calling it from a non-tab context (namely the background page), `tab` will be undefined.

(*): "misunderstood" as in "not bother to read the manual"...

**3.**
It is not clear if you want to close the active tab at the moment the timer is set or at the moment it is triggered. (In your code, you are attempting to do the latter, although the former would make more sense to me.)

---

The correct way to do it:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function message(msg) {
    var ctr = 0;
    ctr = parseInt(msg.text, 10);
    setTimeout(function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function(tabs) {
             chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[0].id);
        });
    }, ctr);
});
```

---

Also, note that using functions like `setTimeout` and `setInteval` will only work reliably in persistent background pages (but not in **[event pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)**). If possible, you are advised to migrate to event pages (which are more "resource-friendly"), in which case you will also have to switch to the **[alarms API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html)**.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a very well written answer.